# Eclipse: Debugger: A way to be notified when a member variable changes value?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to debug a complex application.   The problem is that a member variable of an object is getting set to null at some unidentified point.  There are setters and getters for this member variable, but there are also many places where it is directly accessed and cleared.

Is there a way with the Eclipse debugger that I can be notified whenever this member variable has its value changed?

Comment: Look into "watch".

Answer (score 2):

You can navigate in object hierarchy of references in the "(x)= variables" window (debug perspective). From there, you can also add "watch" on given instance attribute. Right-Clic ->  Toggle Watchpoint.

The program should break on any modification of that instance's attribute.

---

To get the "Watch" feature :

As seen in

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Oxygen Release Milestone 5 (4.7.0 M5)
Build id: 20170202-1353
```

To be sure to have the "watch" option on right clic you can do the following :

1. You need to open Eclipse in the "debug" perspective (Window -> Perspective -> Open Perspective -> debug)
2. You then need to put a breakpoint on your a line that references your variable. Or any line.
3. Run the program in debug (little "bug" icon next to the "play" icon)
4. Once the breakpoint is hit, you can right-clic any variable and get the "watch" option

Otherwise, you can use the "Expressions" window and set your own variables to watch

From there, you can also right clic on a class, and display all of its instances  (right-clic -> all instances).

[image: Exemple of debug perspective with a watch on Java Scanner class "close" attribute (private)]

Answer (score 0):

As duffymo suggested in the comments you can add a Watch Expression.

For example, select the variable you want trace and press the right click. In the menu you'll find the `Watch` option.